# Set context dir for import when include some file in entry.js?

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

In entry.js file I have :
`import 'index.js';`

And that index.js has many imports from another dir like :

`import test from 'modulename'`.

But I have moved all modules to another dir and want to keep just index.js in main dir. So that's why I must rewrite all imports with new dir location like this :
`import test from ../anotherdir/modulename`

How to get rid of this and force webpack to search modules in new dir?

Now I am using webpack allias and this help me if path is too long but it still require to change all imports.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [resolve alias in webpack](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/)

> Resolve
>
> These options change how modules are resolved. webpack provides
>   reasonable defaults, but it is possible to change the resolving in
>   detail. Have a look at Module Resolution for more explanation of how
>   the resolver works.

**webpack.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      Utilities: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/utilities/'),
      Templates: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/templates/')
    }
  }
};
```

Now, instead of using relative paths when importing like so:

```
import Utility from '../../utilities/utility';
```

you can use the alias:

```
import Utility from 'Utilities/utility';
```

Comment: Yes, I use it now but if I just copy not my file with gulp and pass it through webpack stream I can't use it as is and every time it require me to change imports. I thought that it must be a simple to solve with webpack but I can't find how to force webpack seach in another dir when he sees import in my js file.